# What is the name of the font used in the PointlessBlog logo?

Tags: logo, font-identification

What's the name of the font used in this logo's design or something similar to it.

It's a very aesthetically pleasing font.

[image]

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/963215/

Comment: looks like it could be a 60s neon sign

Comment: I don’t think it’s a font; I think it was just drawn manually. You could try contacting someone like [Giga Khurtsilava](https://www.behance.net/gigakhurts9a88), who made the animation effect used at the beginning of the PointlessBlog videos now; he might know. Also, please have a look at the [requirements for font-identification questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Font. Its manually created In software like Illustrator and Photoshop etc.. with the help of pen tool or tablet.